# UserControl Fire Event when a property changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling

`DocField` has a public bool property `IsSelected`
`DocField` implements INotifyPropertyChanged

I need an event that fires in `UserControlDocFieldBaseB` when `DocField.IsSelected` changes.

How do I do that?

```
public partial class UserControlDocFieldBaseB : UserControl
{
    private DocField docField = null;

    public UserControlDocFieldBaseB(DocField DocField)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        docField = DocField;
    }
```

Based on the comment from dkozl this is how I wired it up
UserControlDocFieldString is a fairly expensive so I only want to load it on demand

I suspect I could use the Loaded event rather than the UserControl1_DataContextChanged but this seems to work
It also works with the Loaded event

```
public UserControlDocFieldBaseB()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContextChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(UserControl1_DataContextChanged);
}
void UserControl1_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is UserControlDocFieldBaseB)
    {
        UserControlDocFieldBaseB uc = (UserControlDocFieldBaseB)sender;
        if (uc.DataContext is DocFieldString)
        {
            if (docFieldString == null)
            {
                docFieldString = (DocFieldString)uc.DataContext;
                docFieldString.PropertyChanged += DocFieldString_PropertyChanged;
            } 
        }
    }
}
void DocFieldString_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "IsSelected":
            //MessageBox.Show(docFieldString.Name + " docFieldString.IsSelected " + docFieldString.IsSelected.ToString());
            if (userControlDocFieldString == null && docFieldString != null && docFieldString.IsSelected)
            {
                userControlDocFieldString = new UserControlDocFieldString(docFieldString);
                this.frmEdit.Content = userControlDocFieldString;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `DocField` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `IsSelected` property? If yes then, for example on `Loaded` subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of `DocField` and on `Unloaded` event of `UserControl` unsubscribe and pass on the event if it's for `IsSelected` property

Comment: @dkozl Yes DocField implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  I will try your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DocField` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `IsSelected` property you can simply subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of `DocField`, for example when control is loaded or `DocField` property is changed and pass on the event if it's for `IsSelected property

```
private void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName) || e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
    {
        //pass on the event
    }
}
```