# How to execute internal logic when UserControl property value is changed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web forms WebUserControl that has a Boolean property called `ShowAccessLevels`:

```
Public Property ShowAccessLevels As Boolean
    Get
        Dim a As Object = ViewState("_ShowAccessLevels")
        If a Is Nothing Then
            a = False
        End If
        Return Convert.ToBoolean(a)
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
         ViewState("_ShowAccessLevels") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

When the Setter is called, if the value has changed, I need to execute some internal logic to Show/Hide fields based on the value:

```
Private Sub ShowAccessLevelsChanged()
    If value = False Then
        ' do stuff here
    Else
        ' do stuff here
    End If
End Sub
```

I know that I can call the method from the Setter, but I'm not sure whether this is best practice:

```
Set(value As Boolean)
     If ViewState("_ShowAccessLevels") <> value Then
         ViewState("_ShowAccessLevels") = value
         ShowAccessLevelsChanged()
End Set
```

I will need methods for many different properties, so creating a new one each time feels clunky.  I see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898714/usercontrol-fire-event-when-a-property-changes) has been asked before, but I can't figure out if the final solution matches what the expert and [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) advise.

Please note that I don't need to raise the event outside of the control, its just for internal method use only, which is why I'm struggling to adopt both sources to fit my needs.

If I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` then I end up with these additions, but cannot work out how to link the logic with my property:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
```

I'd appreciate any pointers please.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is going to work just like the alternative Set you provided.  When `value <> _ShowAccessLevels` you would raise the event.  If there are no subscribers to the event, it wont solve anything.  I can show how to implement it, but you'd have the same code in each setter and it will be no less "clunky" than what you have.  The question is whether there is something somewhere subscribing to perhaps precluse the ViewState call.

Comment: Okay that clarification is all I was looking for in the absence of a solution that differed from what I'd done. Thank you.

Comment: you could use a similar *structure* to handle the changes resulting from props rather than a dedicated procedure for each one.

Comment: Can you post any links to information where I can learn more, or post an example that I can accept as the answer please?

Comment: One more clarification - are these reactions to property changes primarily at runtime or responding at design time?  They look like runtime issues, but one cannot always tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cannot work out how to link the logic with my property ... I'd appreciate any pointers please

`INotifyPropertyChanged` would work a bit like you might use `ShowAccessLevelsChanged` except in more generic form:

```vb
Set(value As Boolean)
    If _AccessLevel <> value Then
        _AccessLevel = value
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, 
            New PropertyChangedEventArgs("AccessLevel "))

    End If
End Set
```

`INotifyPropertyChanged` is most commonly used to notify something *external* that a property value changed.   For instance, a `BindingList(Of T)` used as a `DataSource` will watch the `PropertyChanged` event and update the control as a result.

There is *no need* to fire an event only to catch and handle it locally; I'd argue that is *more* clunky.  But the model of one procedure acting as a dispatcher for the various changes might be of value:

```
Set(value As Boolean)
    If (value <> _ShowAccessLevels) Then
        _ShowaccessLevels = value
        UpdateForChange()
    End If
End Set

Private Sub UpdateForChange(<CallerMemberName> Optional propname As String = "")
    Select Case propname
        Case "FooVisible"
            Me.Foo.Visible = FooVisible   ' a simple change

        Case "Bar"
            BuildBarList(Me.Bar)          ' more involved

        Case "ShowAccessLevel"
           UpdateAccess(Me.AccessLevel)   ' very involved (?)
        ...
```

- A private event adds nothing to the mix for local notification.  Raising an event so a local handler can call another method is cruft when you can call the local procedure directly.
- Simple changes can be handled directly in the procedure or it can call specialized helpers when the prop change involves many lines of code.
- There is no need to pass `value` since this will involve boxing and more clunk.  As a local procedure, both the property and backing fields are available *directly*.
- Also the original code seems to conflate backing field names with property names: especially external actors may not associate `FooBar` with `_FooBar`.
- There is not even a need to pass the name of the Property which changed: the above shows using `<CallerMemberName>` which will pass the calling member name to the updater.  It is the same as `UpdateForChange("Foo")` but wont introduce a bug if you paste that to another setter.  It requires NET 4.5 and importing `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` but can very well work without it.
- If most of the reactions are involved, then each setter could call individual, specialized helpers.  There is still no reason to box and pass `value` or even the propname, so the clunk factor is still reduced.

It is common in sub-classed controls to have to do something like this when a property like `BackColor` or `ShowScrollBars` changes.

**Don't rule out `INotifyPropertyChanged` yet**

This is not to say your app could not benefit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The OP code *appears* to use `ViewState` to notify something, somewhere that a property changed. The links in the question are describing how `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be used for that:
  - This class would implement it as a public event and raise it when a prop changes which is of interest to external actors
  - The external class(es) would add `PropertyChanged` event handlers and respond.

The question specifically asks about local handling/notifications and excludes external notices though (and not tagged for MV??).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) _
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub

' Use a writable private backing field for your property.
Private _accessLevels As Boolean = False
Public Property AccessLevels As Boolean
    Get
        Return _accessLevels
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        RefreshAccessLevels(value)
    End Set
End Property

' Next create a method to refresh the property, or optionally pass it an 
' arbitrary value. Call the NotifyPropertyChanged method after updating.
Public Sub RefreshAccessLevels(Optional ByVal newValue As Object = Nothing)
    If newValue IsNot Nothing Then
        _accessLevels = Convert.ToBoolean(newValue)
    Else
        newValue = ViewState("_ShowAccessLevels")
        _accessLevels = If(newValue Is Nothing, False, Convert.ToBoolean(newValue))
    End If
    NotifyPropertyChanged("AccessLevels")
End Sub

' Handle the PropertyChanged event if you need to refresh controls manually
Private Sub HandlePropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Me.PropertyChanged
    Select Case e.PropertyName
        Case "ShowAccessLevels"
            ' Call some refresh logic here...
        Case "SomeOtherProperty"
            ' Etc...
    End Select
End Sub
```

This way, your bound controls are refreshed properly after each update, and you have only one method needed to refresh the value. In the case of a more conventional property with a getter and a setter and no ViewState shenanigans, you just call NotifyPropertyChanged in your setter with no arguments.

```
Private _accessLevels As Boolean = False
Public Property AccessLevels As Boolean
    Get
        Return _accessLevels
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _accessLevels = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

The CallerMemberName attribute takes care of forwarding the calling member's name to the NotifyPropertyChanged method.

This is essentially the basic working of any view model in MVVM and WPF. Define a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, define all your data objects you will need for databinding, instantiate that view model, bind your view (your form) to the instance's property, and update the properties only from your model (general term for The Program...). The idea here is separation of concerns. You should never have to update your form directly through MVVM, the form updates itself according to the view model state.